# Как склонять название поселка Лебяжье?

Tags: склонение, ономастика

Название поселка происходит от лебедей.Чем является название поселка Лебяжье - существительным или прилагательным с зоонимической основой?Как склонять название поселка?

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то этот вопрос однозначно не решается "кабинетными" мнениями. Единственный гарантированный путь - принять вариант, употребляемый местными жителями.

Хотя есть какие-то общие принципы. Большинство таких названий исторически являются усечением полных топонимов типа "Лебежье село" или перенесением на ойконим (название населенного места) близлежащего ландшафтного или природного топонима (озеро Лебяжье). Таким образом название следует считать субстантивированным прилагательным - и склонять его соответствующим образом.

Для современных топонимов, однако, возмжен иной генезис. Тем не менее вариант склонения по парадигме прилагательного: ***Лебяжьего, Лебяжьему***, выглядит более естественным.

Эти топонимы следует отличать от созвучных, но по другому принципу образованных. Типа село Задонье, деревня Прионежье, станция Надуралье, поселок Подмосковье (примеры  условные). Это всегда название местности (Задонье, Прионежье), перенесенное на ойконим. При этом местность в свою очередь названа по другому, еще более значимому объеету (часто - гидрониму) с приставкми "за" или "при", реже - "над" и т.д. Сюда же можно отнести всякие назвния, образованные не от томонимов, а от родовых слов ланшафтных объектов: горов, рек и т.д.: Междуречье, Залесье, Семигорье, Черноземье и т.д. Случаев образования подобных названиий напрямую от других, не природных объектов (в т.ч. зоонимов), я не знаю.

Answer (score 2):

Лебяжье - приложение, то есть является существительным, хотя по форме это прилагательное. Ср.: Думаю о чём?- о Лебяжьем (о посёлке Лебяжьем). Живу в Лебяжьем. Недалеко от Лебяжьего. Склоняется слово как прилагательное.

Answer (score 1):

Авторы справочника "Грамматическая правильность русской речи. Стилистический словарь вариантов" (М., 2001) Граудина Л.К., Ицкович В.А., Катлинская Л.П. считают, что "целесообразно соблюдать два основных правила по употреблению согласуемых форм и несогласуемых форм".
1.  Склоняются:

а) простые (не сложносоставные и не выраженные словосочетаниями) русские, славянские и освоенные названия городов, рек, сел, деревень, поселков, хуторов, усадеб, станиц, кроме оканчивающихся на гласные -о, -Е, -и, -ы.

Таким образом,согласно этому правилу, в поселке Лебяжье.

Comment: Это все так, только вопрос стоит о том *как слонять* **без** родового слова ("озеро", "посклок" и т.д.)